# BorderLayout - Control height but not width

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager

I am relatively new to Java UI and would appreciate your help with a simple problem that I have.

I have a `JPanel` of type `BorderLayout`. The `CENTER` part contains a combo box.

As the outer frame is resized, the panel resizes (this is desired) and the width of the combo box changes (this is desired too). However, the height of the combobox is also changing as the panel is resized. This is not desired.

How can I ensure that my combo box expands in width but not in height?

I also have a button in `LINE_START`. I would like this button not to stretch at all.

Comment: Post code showing what you've achieved so far.

Comment: Posting code will be much appreciated, that way, we can look, under given criteria, how your window can look nice with different settings. So [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) PLEASE, I am waiting for one :-)

Answer (score 6):

Put the combo. into the `NORTH` of a panel that is then added to the `CENTER` of the main `BorderLayout`.  Do the same with the button.

Comment: +1 Neat answer. Would it also make sure that the button is not resized? I guess if it is set as `LINE_START` the height would stretch anyway, right?

Comment: @Boro I missed mention of the 'button' & expanded my answer to cover it.

Answer (score 5):

I would strongly suggest for you to use TableLayout my personal favourite. Since you can layout your elements as if they were in a table, without much hassle.

[You can read more about it here.](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/tablelayout/)

[This link takes you to a full site about it.](http://www.clearthought.info/sun/products/jfc/tsc/articles/tablelayout/)

I am afraid this layout manager might be slightly outdated, certainly the examples on its page are, but it works great even in 1.7 version of `Java`.

Look at the example there. The option you would use to make the box to stretch (i.e. fill the available space) is `TableLayout.FILL`.