# Design view in Netbeans won't load

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I started to learn swing and downloaded netbeans to work through the tutorials. Unfortunately, when I create a JFrame design view hangs instead of loading and the Navigator and Inspector panes just show up empty.

```
System details:  
Linux Mint Maya
Netbeans version 7.0.1  
java 1.6.0_24
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try an [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) that _doesn't_ use the GUI designer.

Comment: I'm obviously going to work through those but I would like to learn how to use the GUI designer as well, which I can't if I can't get it working.

Comment: Use a process of elimination: What happens when try an example that doesn't use the GUI designer? Is all of NetBeans broken on your distribution? Just the GUI designer. Just your code?

Comment: Just the GUI designer. I tried a previous example that doesn't use it and it ran fine. The GUI designer generates code which requires me to add a library to the package. I thought that would solve it, but it didn't.

Comment: Maybe it is a sign that it is better to learn layout managers and stick to them rather than relaying on GUI designer. :) I would strongly recommend the [TableLayout](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10495928/613495) it is my personal favourite.

Comment: That may very well be. Either way I'm switching back to eclipse and vim.

Comment: to check for bugtraces on Netbeans pages, maybe this bug is closed, maybe not

Comment: @Yitzchak: The designer requires `GroupLayout`, new in Java 6, but there may be others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In whatever editor/designer you choose, consider the approach shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2561540/230513), in which the [top-level container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) is created manually and one or more content panels are maintained in the designer.

Comment: GUI designers keep metadata; NetBeans uses `.form` files containing xml in the `src` tree. Commit frequently. :-)

Answer (score 3):

look in the Netbeans View menu and choose "IDE log"
There may be an error message / exception there, that might give you a clue.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling the nb-javac plugin fixed this issue for me.

I followed the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60830514) and it resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was caused by a "FormGuardedBlockError", because at one point in my project I copied all of the source out into Notepad++ and used that to replace the `.java` file, thereby stripping all of the `//GEN-BEGIN` and related directives.

You can close NetBeans, open the `.java` file in a plaintext editor and put these directives back by hand, but it may be easier to merge with an earlier version of your code (if you have one).

For more details, check out http://wiki.netbeans.org/FormGuardedBlockError

Answer (score 0):

Menu->view->show edit toolbar  fixed this for me , of course the file you select to edit must have jframe,  added to it I think for design tab to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Menu -> Option -> Select "Java" from option windows tool 
then Active